# add ordering column in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to do in sql oracle a time scheduling query. For each employee, I have to show which day he is working or not. Sometimes the person can have a work schedule on two weeks. For example in week 1 he doesn't work Monday, Tuesday and Friday and the week 2 he doesn't work at Monday and Friday.

I already get the query but sometimes the result doesn't start at Monday.
I want to add a weeknumber so I am able to order.  Example:

```
empl    date        day_nbr Working
1       01/11/2017  3       FULLDAY
1       02/11/2017  4       FULLDAY
1       03/11/2017  5       OFF
1       04/11/2017  6       OFF
1       05/11/2017  7       OFF
1       06/11/2017  1       OFF
1       07/11/2017  2       FULLDAY
1       08/11/2017  3       FULLDAY
1       09/11/2017  4       FULLDAY
1       10/11/2017  5       OFF
1       11/11/2017  6       OFF
1       12/11/2017  7       OFF
1       13/11/2017  1       OFF
1       14/11/2017  2       OFF
2       01/09/2018  6       OFF
2       02/09/2018  7       OFF
2       03/09/2018  1       FULLDAY
2       04/09/2018  2       FULLDAY
2       05/09/2018  3       OFF
2       06/09/2018  4       FULLDAY
2       07/09/2018  5       FULLDAY
```

For `empl=1` you see the week begins at `day_nbr 3`. I want to add a column weeknumber so I have following result:

```
empl    date        day_nbr Working     weeknumber
1       01/11/2017  3       FULLDAY     1
1       02/11/2017  4       FULLDAY     1
1       03/11/2017  5       OFF         1
1       04/11/2017  6       OFF         1
1       05/11/2017  7       OFF         1
1       06/11/2017  1       OFF         2
1       07/11/2017  2       FULLDAY     2
1       08/11/2017  3       FULLDAY     2
1       09/11/2017  4       FULLDAY     2
1       10/11/2017  5       OFF         2
1       11/11/2017  6       OFF         2
1       12/11/2017  7       OFF         1
1       13/11/2017  1       OFF         1
1       14/11/2017  2       OFF         1
2       01/09/2018  6       OFF         1
2       02/09/2018  7       OFF         1
2       03/09/2018  1       FULLDAY     1
2       04/09/2018  2       FULLDAY     1
2       05/09/2018  3       OFF         1
2       06/09/2018  4       FULLDAY     1
2       07/09/2018  5       FULLDAY     1
```

In that way I can order on `weeknumber`, `day_nbr` and I will always start at day_nbr 1.

The reason I want to do that is to be able to make a pivot table like this for empl=1

[image: result I want]

But the problem I get this:

[image: result if I don't have the week_nbr]

Comment: Hello, is date a date column? Order the table by empl and date will works

Comment: As stated above, you already appear to have the columns you need. You can just order by date (and empl if you want that, hard to tell from example) even day_nbr seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: No If I order by date, my week does not begins at the day_nbr 1. If 01/11/2017 is a wedsneday, I will start at day number 3.